# Binary image perimeter coordinate out of bounds - java

Tags: java, arrays, image

I am attempting to get the perimeter off a binary image however I keep getting the error 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: ' can anyone identify how i can fix this issue?

```
    int perimeter = 0;  
    Raster raster = source.getRaster();

    for (int i = 1; i<source.getHeight();i++){
        for(int j =1; j<source.getWidth();j++){
            if(raster.getSample(j, i, 0) == 0){
                if(raster.getSample(j+1, i, 0) == 1 || raster.getSample(j-1, i, 0) == 1 || raster.getSample(j, i+1, 0) == 1 || raster.getSample(j, i-1, 0) == 1){
                    perimeter++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?  Have you thought about edge-of-image conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int perimeter = 0;  
Raster raster = source.getRaster();

for (int i=1; i<source.getHeight()-1; i++) {
    for (int j=1; j<source.getWidth()-1; j++) {
        if (raster.getSample(j, i, 0) == 0) {
            if (raster.getSample(j+1, i, 0) == 1
             || raster.getSample(j-1, i, 0) == 1
             || raster.getSample(j, i+1, 0) == 1
             || raster.getSample(j, i-1, 0) == 1) {
                perimeter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, inside of your double-for-loop, you are checking the neighbors of the current element (the neighbors above, below, left, and right). This means that there needs to be a left, right, above, and below neighbor in order for the code to work. So we can't run the loop on the boundary elements (any element that might not have a left, right, above, or below neighbor).

So my solution is to alter the for loops so it skips the boundary elements. If you need to check the boundary elements too, then you might have to make some changes to the inside of your for loop.

Comment: This works! :) I see what I did wrong, thanks! will accept you as the correct answer

Comment: Glad to help! I added some more comments in case someone else comes across this page.